# Apple TV (1080HD) - Macbook to HDTV Streaming Issues

Tags: macbook-pro, appletv, streaming, television

I have the brand new [$99 Apple TV - 1080HD](http://www.apple.com/appletv/)

I want to stream internet videos from my 2011 Macbook Pro (running Snow Leopard) to my new HDTV using Airplay and AirParrot.  Neither the Macbook nor the Apple TV is connected via ethernet cable -- they are both connected to the internet via our wireless router (currently, there's no ethernet jack near the TV).

When I stream the video on my MBP, it is **extremely choppy** with **very poor image quality**.  I've played with all the AirParrot preferences (reduced video quality to eliminate choppiness, etc), yet nothing works.

In order to fix the issue, which of the following (if any) is the best bet for a technophobe like myself:

1. Install an ethernet jack near the TV because my wireless signal may be too weak (real dumb question: would I connect the Apple TV or my MBP to the ethernet jack?)
2. Forget Airplay and connect my MacBook Pro directly to my computer
3. Install an additional wireless router closer to the Apple TV
4. Get a repeater to expand the reach of the wireless signal from my one router.
5. None of the above.

If I need any additional adapters/wires, please specify so that this moron will understand.

Thank you all so much for any help you can offer.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to Mountain Lion? It is probably the easiest and least expensive way to get direct video streaming and you don't have to use any third-party applications.

Comment: "soxman" -- thank you so much for the reply.

there seem to be so many people on here, and elsewhere, complaining about the problems Mountain Lion is causing (in all areas), i'm hesitant to upgrade for this sole purpose.  otherwise, i'd definitely be game for it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a new Apple TV and stream from iPhones, iPads and various macs via AirPlay... and love it!

Two places I'd suggest you focus:

- the operating system

  - upgrade to 10.8 (if you don't want to commit to ML, install it on a partition, thumb drive or RAM card and boot from there to AirPlay)
  - while not a principle cause of what you're experiencing, how much RAM does your MacBook have? If you have 4GB or less, upgrading to 8GB is a small dollar investment that provides a great return in speed.
- the wireless router

  - are you experiencing slow or choppy wifi performance anywhere other than AirPlay?
  - does your MacBook Pro intermittently drop its wifi connection even when you have a full signal?
  - what wireless router(s) do you have, and how old are they?

    - just because it says G or N doesn't mean the wifi router is "any good" or supports all the protocols needed for AirPlay
  - how far is the wireless router from your tv and MacBook?

    - within reason, the closer the better

You call yourself a technophobe and moron, and I'm not here to dispute either of them (but I think you can achieve what you're hoping for!). My simple suggestion to resolve your problem: replace your wifi router with an Apple AirPort Extreme (less than $200) or AirPort Express (about $100).

- I have used macs and iOS devices with a number of different brands of wireless routers, to limited success and happiness, usually defendant upon the age of the router. Older wifi gear does not support all the tricks and new technology Apple (and Intel) builds into the newer computers.
- I've had the best success with Apple's AirPort Extreme or Express base stations... for working with both Macs and Windows boxes.

  - the AirPort Extreme let's you hook up a USB hard drive as a centralized TimeMachine backup disk for all your Macs backups
  - both the Extreme and Express let you attach a USB printer for remote printing

Either of the two routers are quick to set up, work with your Internet gateway, and should accomplish what you need. If you have an Apple store nearby, swing by and pick one up. You already have the software on your MacBook to configure it.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much for the very helpful information and advice, tom.  i will definitely look into the options you mentioned above and see if they fix the issue.  again, thanks for your time...